# How to add a simple tab in Intellij Idea plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs, intellij-plugin

I am creating a simple class diagram plugin for Intellij Idea. I'm struggling now with creating a simple tab in IDE. This tab I will fill up with a prepared JPanel and nothing else.
I have already done the same in NetBeans and I would like to find something with similar behavior as TopComponent in NetBeans provides, but anything working would be cool.

Comment: I prefer Java only solution, if possible

Comment: You may create JCEF component as describe here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/jcef.html

Comment: Does that help you: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tool-windows.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer:

1. create implementation of `com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileEditor`. This is your actual tab
2. create implementation of `com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.FileEditorProvider`
   `accept()` defines type of files which your editor opens
   `create()` should returns the proper instance of your editor
3. register your FileEditoProvider in `plugin.xml`

Editor:

```
public class YourEditor implements FileEditor {

    private VirtualFile file;
    
    public YourEditor(VirtualFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull JComponent getComponent() {
        JPanel tabContent = new JPanel();
        tabContent.add(new JButton("foo"));
        return tabContent;
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable JComponent getPreferredFocusedComponent() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public @Nls(capitalization = Nls.Capitalization.Title)
    @NotNull String getName() {
        return "name";
    }

    @Override
    public void setState(@NotNull FileEditorState fileEditorState) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isModified() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(@NotNull PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(@NotNull PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener) {
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable FileEditorLocation getCurrentLocation() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        Disposer.dispose(this);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> @Nullable T getUserData(@NotNull Key<T> key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void putUserData(@NotNull Key<T> key, @Nullable T t) {

    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable VirtualFile getFile() {
        return this.file;
    }
}
```

Provider:

```
public class YourEditorProvider implements FileEditorProvider, DumbAware {

    private static String EDITOR_TYPE_ID = "DiagramView";

    @Override
    public boolean accept(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull VirtualFile virtualFile) {
        return true; //will accept all kind of files, must be specified
    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull
    FileEditor createEditor(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull VirtualFile virtualFile) {
        return new YourEditor(virtualFile);
    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull
    @NonNls
    String getEditorTypeId() {
        return EDITOR_TYPE_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public @NotNull
    FileEditorPolicy getPolicy() {
        return FileEditorPolicy.HIDE_DEFAULT_EDITOR;
    }
}
```

and finally put FileEditorProvider extension in `pluxin.xml`:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <fileEditorProvider implementation="classDiagramPainter.DiagramViewProvider"/>
</extensions>
```

Comment: Note that newer versions of IntelliJ will throw an exception if getUserData() and putUserData() are not implemented properly.

Comment: @lbarowski
Thanks. Could you advise me, what is a proper implementation, or what is the propouse of those? I cannot find any docs for this.

Comment: The test that IntelliJ does just puts a value and makes sure it can then get it, so storing the values in a map is probably all that is necessary. I have not tried yet, but it looks like you can just extend com.intellij.openapi.util.UserDataHolderBase and the work should be done for you.